# How to prove the following statements about tangent lines to $y=ax^2+bx+c$?

Tags: calculus

Consider the graph of the equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$, $a≠0$. Prove the following:

a. If $a$ and $c$ have the same sign, that is $ac > 0$, then there are exactly two tangent lines to the graph that pass through the origin.

b. If $a$ and $c$ have opposite signs, that is $ac < 0$, then no tangent line to the graph passes through the origin.

c. What happens if $c=0$?

I understand the concepts above if I draw it out, but I just don't know how to go about proving it with math. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Hint: How would you find the slope of a tangent through the origin?

Comment: The line thru the point $(x_1,y_1)$ with slope $s_1$ is $L_1=\{(x,y): (y-y_1)=s_1(x-x_1)\}.$   So $(0,0)\in L_1$ iff $-y_1=(0-y_1)=s_1(0-x_1)=-s_1 x_1.$  So if $y_1=ax_1^2+bx_1+c$ and $s_1=2ax_1+b,$  is it possible that $-y_1=-s_1x_1 $ for some (or any)    values of $x_1$?

Answer (score 2):

A line through the origin has the equation $y=mx$. It tangents the parabola if it makes a "double" intersection with it.

In other words,
$$mx=ax^2+bx+c$$

must have a double root. This occurs when the discriminant

$$(b-m)^2-4ac$$ is zero and is only possible when $ac\ge0$, giving the solutions

$$m=b\pm2\sqrt{ac}.$$

You can conclude for c.

---

Alternatively, the tangent at $x=t$ has the equation

$$y=(2at+b)(x-t)+at^2+bt+c.$$

It passes through the origin if

$$0=-(2at+b)t+at^2+bt+c$$ or

$$-at^2+c=0.$$

The discussion of the number of solutions in $t$ is easy.